# nodejs stringformat package, has no method format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I install the nodejs stringformat pacakage, and I run their first example:
https://npmjs.org/package/stringformat

but I get the following error:

```
> npm install stringformat
> node
> var $ = require('stringformat')
> console.log($.format("Hello, {0}!", "World"))
TypeError: Object function () {
            // Call as a method
            return format.apply(arguments[0], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
        } has no method 'format'
    at repl:1:16
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
>
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have a `format()` method.

You can use it either as a function:

```
 console.log($("Hello, {0}!", "World"))
```

or by enabling `String` extension:

```
 $.extendString();
 // here, you call format() on a String instance .
 console.log("Hello, {0}!".format("World"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I see; the doc is up to date at https://github.com/jcayzac/stringformat.js  but not at https://npmjs.org/package/stringformat